# How do you dynamically assign aliases in a django aggregate?

Tags: python, django, django-models, aggregate-functions, django-queryset

I'm trying out the [django aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). I'm dynamically calling these aggregates and need to assign and alias them on the fly. I want the resulting alias to be the name of the original field.

For example:

```
from django.db import models as aggregator

field = 'person'
reducer = getattr(aggregator, 'Sum')

query_set.aggregate(field=reducer(field))
```

I'm expecting this:

```
{'person':12}
```

But getting this:

```
{'field':12}
```

Is there a way I can dynamically assign the alias in this case?

Comment: Try: `query_set.aggregate(**{field:reducer(field)})`

Comment: You're welcome. Also posted this as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `unpack` syntax and pass a dictionary:

```
query_set.aggregate(**{field:reducer(field)})
```